# Python lxml etree remove tail from element

Tags: python, elementtree

I have an element which contains a `<p>` element and a tail.

for example:
`<p>Content that I want to keep</p>content that I want removed`

I notice that the content that needs to be removed is in the tail, and I would think that there is an easy way to remove the tail from an element using etree.

How would I be able to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After working on this for a couple of hours the answer just came to me. (Of course right after posting the question)

I just set the tail to None:

```
element = root.xpath("path/to/element")
element[0].tail = None
string = tostring(element[0])
```

And it works.

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but for the benefit of others looking for an answer, if the goal is "remove tail to call etree.tostring()", then you don't need to modify the tree:

https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tostring

```
string = tostring(element[0], with_tail=False)
```

Comment: Thanks; this was very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Use [elementsoup](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html) from lxml package:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring

s = """<p>Content that I want to keep</p>content that I want removed"""

print fromstring(s).find('.//p').text
```